# Search for class element underneath another element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I scrape daily lineups, and need to find out if a team does not have it's lineup posted. In this case, there is a class element called lineup__no. I'd like to look at each team and check if there lineup is posted, and if not, add that teams index to a list. For example, if there are 4 teams playing, and the first and third teams do not have a lineup posted, I want to return a list of [0,2]. I am guessing a list comprehension of some sort may help me get there, but struggling to come up with what I need. I tried a for loop for now to get each of the items under the main header. I've also tried adding each li item's text to a list and searching for "Unknown Lineup" but was unsuccessful.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

#Scraping lineups for updates
url = 'https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/daily-lineups.php'

##Requests rotowire HTML
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

games = soup.select('.lineup.is-mlb')
for game in games:
    initial_list = game.find_all('li')
    print(initial_list)
```

Comment: I do not see any `lineup__no` inside any element blocks matching `.lineup.is-mlb`. can you please clarify your question more?

Comment: I'll admit I am not the greatest at finding specific elements so maybe there is an easier way to get to it, but If I run it right now (which may change as teams get their lineups posted, it returns this at the end (cut some out for space).
</li>, <li class="lineup__status">
<div class="dot is-medium" style="margin-right:5px;"></div>Unknown Lineup
</li>, <li class="lineup__no"><p>The Athletics lineup has not been posted yet.</p>
</li>, <li class="lineup__status"></div>Unknown Lineup
</li>, <li class="lineup__no"><p>The Reds lineup has not been posted yet.</p></li>]

Comment: Most teams have posted their lineups, so it is only the very last two teams at this moment that have not been posted, but this will change and may have to wait until tomorrow if the lineup gets posted.

Comment: I see. Can I give you a Selenium, not a bs4 solution here?

Comment: I'm more familiar with bs4, but if you have a selenium solution, I'm happy to see that too. Anything that can help out is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm more familiar with Selenium I'll give you Selenium solution.
Please see my explanations inside the code given as comments.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/daily-lineups.php")
#wait for at least 1 game element to be visible
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lineup.is-mlb")))
#add a short delay so that all the other games are loaded
time.sleep(0.5)
#get all the games blocks
games = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".lineup.is-mlb")
#iterate over the games elements with their indexes in a list comprehension
no_lineup = [j for idx, game in enumerate(games) for j in [idx*2, idx*2+1] if game.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//li[@class='lineup__no']")] 


#print the collected results
print(no_lineup)
#quit the driver
driver.quit()
```

Comment: That got me 98 percent of the way there, but unfortunately it was only returning 0-13 in a list, as opposed to 0-27. It was looking only at each game it seems, and not each team possibly? I ended up using most of your code with the exception of putting it into a list comprehension and adding something to make it get every team. Here is the line of code replacing that last for loop.                                                                            
 no_lineup = [j for idx, game in enumerate(games) for j in [idx*2, idx*2+1] if game.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//li[@class='lineup__no']")]

Comment: First of all I'm really happy I could help you. In case there are still 2% problems existing as you mentioned, please ask another, new question for that

Comment: I was able to solve it and I posted the last piece of it in the comments. Should I edit your answer to add that in? Because the rest of it was perfect.

Comment: You are welcome to edit my answer, sure

Answer (score 1):

Simply just look under the `<li>` tags with `class="lineup__status"`. And then use `enumerate` to track the index of the list as you iterate through. I don't have an example of some teams having a lineup in (I'll have to check later as the lineups get populated here), so I'd likely change the logic of `if lineupStatus.text.strip() == 'Unknown Lineup'` to be more robust. But until I can see exactly how the html looks at that point, I'll have to assume `"lineup__no" class is present always. But like I said, once I see how this page looks with some lineups in, I'll adjust it.

By the way,

`The Guardians lineup has not been posted yet.`

threw me off there for a second...totally forgot about that!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

#Scraping lineups for updates
url = 'https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/daily-lineups.php'

##Requests rotowire HTML
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

lineupStatuses = soup.find_all('li', {'class':re.compile('^lineup__status')})


noLineupIndex = []
for idx, lineupStatus in enumerate(lineupStatuses):
    if 'is-confirmed' not in lineupStatus['class']:
        noLineupIndex.append(idx)
        
# Or use list comprehension        
#noLineupIndex = [idx for idx, lineupStatus in enumerate(lineupStatuses) if 'is-confirmed' not in lineupStatus['class']]
```

**Output:**

```
print(noLineupIndex)
[0, 3, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
```

Comment: I did too until you pointed it out. While your answer is helpful as well, it doesn't quite get me what I was seeking. I wanted a list with the team index. In this case, no one has posted a lineup so it would have been a list of [0....end]. I do appreciate your answer though as it does help me better my web scraping skills.

Comment: Ah ok. Easy fix. I’ll adjust it in the morning.

Comment: And what do you mean a a list of [0…end]? Do you mean an empty list?

Comment: Your answer actually did help a lot because I realized what I had above had a slight mistake. I'll update the answer to include some of your response, but what I was looking for was not an empty list, but I wanted the index of the team as shown in the question. For example, in your code, if the Red Sox and Twins were the only two teams without lineups posted, it would return [1,3].

Comment: ah ok. Got you. So a list of of the index of the teams without a lineups. So essentially is every team has a lineup, then it would be empty

Comment: ok adjusted the code above.

Comment: @ShawnSchreier, ok now the code is code. Looks like when a lineup is confirmed, they attach that to the lineup__status class. So basically the code looks at each lineup, if it's not confirmed, it adds the index to the list. So you are left with the index values of teams with no confirmed lineup

Comment: Your first response was actually a bit better because I don't mind if the lineup is not confirmed. I just want to know if there is no lineup posted whatsoever. However, I realized I had an issue in the prior code and ended up using your original response a bit more.

Comment: This is what I used - it won't let me edit the final answer right now. lineupStatuses = soup.find_all('li', {'class':'lineup__status'})

noLineup = [idx for idx, game in enumerate(lineupStatuses) if game.parent.find('li', {'class':'lineup__no'})]

Comment: Thanks again for your help. It is extremely helpful and helped me get to the final code.

Comment: Ah cool. I edit to put the old code.